# What's the difference between という方に会いました and と会いました?

Tags: translation, meaning, word-choice

1. つぐみさんという方に会いました.
2. つぐみさんと会いました.

What does '方に' mean here? and 'いう' too.

Comment: 「という方に」についての質問なら、「つぐみさん**という方に**会いました」と「つぐみさん**に**会いました」を比べたほうがいいのでは・・・

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two sentences are rather similar in meaning but the key differences are the ones you highlight.

First off, という is quotative that makes what comes before it something being quoted.

Here, [方]{かた} means a person.

So

> 1. つぐみさんという方に会いました。

= I met the person named Tsumugi-san.

vs.

> 2. つぐみさんと会いました。

= I met Tsumugi-san

The second one has just that meaning and functions in roughly the same contexts at the English sentence that translates it.

The という方 version emphasizes (after a sense) this is the name of the person you met.

1. The person you are speaking to does not know who Tsumugi-san is.
2. You had prior information about this person from the person you are talking to.
3. That you are indicating this is the name they gave you...